# Random background image for multiple jumbotrons on same page

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm using jumbotrons which display a background-image to break up text-heavy pages. I have a folder in which I placed several background images and use javascript to pull an image from this folder to use as a background image. I got the ideas from this stackoverflow question:  [Random image on page load as Jumbotron background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984107/random-image-on-page-load-as-jumbotron-background)

It works fine as after every page load another image is display. However, all the jumbotrons get the same image. I actually want these jumbotrons to display different background images from the folder.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? I could add more classes and let js pull a different image for each class. But this seems not clean and concise to me.

p.s. I cannot add the folder with the background images to the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = ['background-img_1.webp', 'background-img_2.webp', 'background-img_3.webp', 'background-img_4.webp', 'background-img_5.webp'];

  $('.jumbotron-fluid').css({
    'background-image': 'url(../_assets/img/background-img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'
  });
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  padding: 1.875rem;
  margin: 1.875rem 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none
}

background-color: grey;
color: black;

}
.jumbotron-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid my-5">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = ['background-img_1.webp', 'background-img_2.webp', 'background-img_3.webp', 'background-img_4.webp', 'background-img_5.webp'];

  $('.jumbotron-fluid').each(function() {
    var randomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    $(this).css({
      'background-image': 'url(../_assets/img/background-img/' + randomImage + ')'
    });
  });
});
```

With this code, each jumbotron will have a different randomly selected background image from the images array. Note that it's still possible for two or more jumbotrons to have the same background image due to the random selection.

Comment: Works like a dime. I do need to familiarise myself with Javascript. You can do a lot of gr8 things with it.